How to remove bottom and top padding from SwiftUI List in Xcode15
I'm trying to remove the default padding top and bottom added by the list in SwiftUi. I have a list that shows the tasks to be completed. Padding top and bottom is added by default when i created the list and I tried using " .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())" to remove the padding top and bottom of the list. But failed. I'm trying to fix this issue from past 2 days by trying other ways, but I'm unable to fix it. The padding top and bottom looks like When only 1 task is present and this space (white space at the bottom) after the list is irrespective of how many tasks are added to the list and displayed, it has the same padding bottom and top, even when there are 2 tasks present.When 2 tasks are present.I want to remove the top and bottom padding that is created by the list. I believe that the padding is due to the list. I want to use list here but I also want to remove the padding bottom and top created by the list. (The padding decreases as I add things to favourites and the padding increases when i remove things from favourites(that is present after the list at the bottom) because of the list used. If I remove the list, all works fine). I want the padding top and bottom of the list to be removed.Could you please suggest what can be done to overcome this problem?
struct TaskView: View {
    @State private var selectedItem: activityItem?
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Text("TASK LIST")
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .padding(.leading, 40)
                .padding(.top, 15)
                .padding(.bottom, 5)

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Total")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                        Text("5")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("TASK COMPLETED")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                        Text("3")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top, 5)
                .padding(.bottom, 0)
                .padding(.leading, 16)
                .padding(.trailing, 16)
                
                
                if !activityInfo.isEmpty  {
                    Divider()
                        .frame(height: 1)
                        .background(Color.gray)
                        .padding(.top, 0)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 25)

                    List {
                        ForEach(activityInfo) { item in
                            HStack
                            {
                              
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text("Task1")
                                        .font(.title2)
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                     Text("3 to 4")
                                        .font(.subheadline)
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                }
                               
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                                  
                                            Text("Dance") 
                                           
                                    
                                    HStack {
                                     Text("Monday")
                                    }
                                }
                               
                            
                                
                            }
                            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                            .padding(.vertical, 0)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                         self.selectedItem = item
                                           }
                        }
                        .onMove(perform: move)
                    }
                   
                   .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                    .background(Color.clear.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
                    
                }

            }
            
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
        }
    }
    func move(source: IndexSet, destination: Int) {
        activityInfo.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
        }
    
    }


I have mentioned in black(Space remove text), the extra space that should be removed at the bottom and i even want the top padding to be removed.the space that is marked as "Space Remove" should be removed. I'm using Xcode 15
